# What happens when I call a Javascript function which takes parameters, without supplying those parameters?

Tags: javascript, parameters

What happens when I call a Javascript function which takes parameters, without supplying those parameters?

Comment: Well, what did happen when you called a Javascript function which takes parameters, without supplying those parameters? Pray tell.

Comment: Well there were no errors.. thats why I was wondering..

Comment: presumably, parts of the code executed until it hit a NPE, or no NPE occurred, or a NPE occurred immediately. observing any of these scenarios are very different from gaining a rigid understanding of how javascript handles arguments (which is, as with many other aspects of js, not very obvious, but quite neat once you know how to utilize it)

Comment: I believe they asked the question because they're from a background where that could be a **serious** problem, in languages like c it would error, badly. So they know that nothing happened **that** time, but as something could go wrong in another scenario, and he came here to find out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens if I don't pass a parameter in a Javascript function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107823/what-happens-if-i-dont-pass-a-parameter-in-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Set to undefined.  You don't get an exception.  It can be a convenient method to make your function more versatile in certain situations.  Undefined evaluates to false, so you can check whether or not a value was passed in.

Comment: And what if your function can take five parameters, but you only supply two? Same thing?

Comment: the first two are accepted, the following three are set to undefined

Comment: furthermore, you can acctually supply *more* parameters than the function accepts. you can then access all parameters by the `arguments` collection. `function test(param1) { alert(param1); if(arguments.length == 2) alert(arguments[1]); } test(); test(1); test(1,2);`

Answer (score 21):

javascript will set any missing parameters to the value `undefined`.

```
function fn(a) {
    console.log(a);
}

fn(1); // outputs 1 on the console
fn(); // outputs undefined on the console
```

This works for any number of parameters.

```
function example(a,b,c) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
}

example(1,2,3); //outputs 1 then 2 then 3 to the console
example(1,2); //outputs 1 then 2 then undefined to the console
example(1); //outputs 1 then undefined then undefined to the console
example(); //outputs undefined then undefined then undefined to the console
```

also note that the `arguments` array will contain all arguments supplied, even if you supply more than are required by the function definition.

Answer (score 9):

There is the inverse to everyones answer in that you can call a function that doesnt appear to have parameters in the signature with parameters.

You can then access them using the built in `arguments` global. This is an array that you can get the details out of it.

e.g.

```
function calcAverage() 
{ 
   var sum = 0 
   for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) 
      sum = sum + arguments[i] 
   var average = sum/arguments.length 
   return average 
} 
document.write("Average = " + calcAverage(400, 600, 83))
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the comments above, the **arguments** array has zero length.  One can examine it rather than the parameters named in the function signature.

Answer (score -8):

You get an exception as soon as you try to use one of the parameters.