# What happens if I don't pass a parameter in a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, overloading

I am new to the world of Javascript and am tinkering with writing very basic functions and stumbled upon the example below by accident and am unsure why it works when I am not passing a parameter when the function demands it.

**Sample function**

```
function myfunction(x) {
    alert("This is a sample alert");
}
```

Now if I call the function `myfunction();` I am presented with the alert. Why is that that I am able to call the function without any errors or warnings when I have not passed a parameter?

**EDIT**

I did not expect so many great answers and I am by no means in a position yet able to say which answer is the best so am I able to request people to suggest the best answer and I'll award the acceptance to that person.

Comment: Might also be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: There is no overloading based upon function signatures in JS so it really doesn't care how many params the function "expects". You can even pass in params that the function isn't defined to take and just use the keyword arguments to retrieve them.

Comment: @scrappedcola - What do you mean by overloading as well as pass in parameters that the function isn't defined to take? Can you give examples?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey. He meant, you can't have two functions: `function foo(x){...}` and `function foo(x,y,z){...}` you can have only one function for each name.

Comment: @gdoron - Does having a function with the same name mean `overloading`?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey. Yes, you can't have `function overloading` in js, you have other ways though to mock it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when I call a Javascript function which takes parameters, without supplying those parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846679/what-happens-when-i-call-a-javascript-function-which-takes-parameters-without-s)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Nothing will happen- meaning you won't get an error or a warning as passing the parameters in javascript is optional.
All the parameters that weren't "supplied" will have the [`undefined` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

```
function foo(x, y, z){
    //...
}

foo(1);
```

Inside the `foo` function now:

```
function foo(x, y, z){
    x === 1
    y === undefined
    z === undefined
}
```

You can even pass more arguments, like:

```
foo(1,2,3,4,5,7); // Valid!
```

You can know the amounts of parameters supplied by `arguments.length` from inside the function.

```js
function foo(x, y, z) {
    console.log('x value: ' + x);
    console.log('y value: ' + y);
    console.log('z value: ' + z);
    console.log('Arguments length: ' + arguments.length);
}
console.log('Zero parameters');
foo();
console.log('Four parameters');
foo(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Example of useful function that handle any amount of parameters:

```js
function max() {
    var maxValue = arguments[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (maxValue < arguments[i]) {
            maxValue = arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}

alert(max(1, 5, 7, 2, 88, 32, 44));
```

Comment: Thanks for the live demo. Did not expect so many good answers. So if I have a function such as `function myfunction (a,b){}` and passed the values myfunction(1,2,3,4,5), I take it that it is still valid? Is the expectation that there will be some warning or error?

Comment: Sorry, would you mind elaborating what the command `console.log` does as well as arguments.length?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey. Valid! no warning no error, it be even useful, I'll give you a demo in a moment.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nxf2q/). And `console.log` is like an alert, click the F12 button.

Comment: Whoa. That's a fair bit to digest in the code. I take it that the console.log only works in Google Chrome and Firefox? Also an alert if only given if there is an error or warning?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey. It works with IE as well if you have the developers console installed, I think it is installed by default from IE8+. I didn't understand what you wrote about `alert`.

Comment: I did not know that IE had a developers console. That's a great thing to know. +1 for that. Sorry. What I mean by `alert` is that if I use the command `console.log`, an alert or warning is displayed if it occurs. If there are no errors in the code, the console.log returns nothing.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey. I still don't get that comment. Are you using IE? If you do, what version? Did you mean you get an error when you use `console.log`?

Comment: Sorry. I'll try and explain better. So if I have the function `function myfunction(a,b,c,d,e){return a+b;console.log(arguments);} and call the function as `document.write(myfunction(1,2));` the console would only log an error or warning for c,d,e as being undefined as no values were passed?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey. **1.** You can't have code after `return` it's being ignored. **2.** you will not get errors or warnings. [See this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zvFNn/)

Comment: Amazing the number of things you learn in a single post. So that I take it that I can't have a single line of code after `return`?  I had a look at the console in Google Chrome and I see it outputs the contents of each of the parameters. Why would you use console.log? Debugging?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12762/discussion-between-gdoron-and-peanutsmonkey)

Answer (score 12):

All arguments in JavaScript functions are optional (read "loosely typed").

> JavaScript functions can be invoked with any number of arguments,
>   regardless of  the number of arguments named in the function
>   definition. Because a function is  loosely typed, there is no way for
>   it to declare the type of arguments it expects,  and it is legal to
>   pass values of any type to any function. When a function is invoked with fewer arguments than are declared, the additional arguments have the undefined value.

You can refer to a function's arguments within the function by using the named argument variables or the arguments object. This object contains an entry for each argument passed to the function, the first entry's index starting at 0. For example, if a function is passed three arguments, you can refer to the argument as follows:

```
arguments[0]
arguments[1]
arguments[2]
```

- JavaScript - The Definitive Guide, 5th Edition

Answer (score 7):

That's just how JavaScript works. Parameters are optional, and will have the not-really-a-value value "undefined" in the function if they're missing from a function call.

By "optional" I mean just that: invoking *any* function involves an arbitrarily long list of parameters. There need be no relationship between the number of parameters *passed* to a function and the number *declared*.  Best way to think of this declaration, then:

```
function x(a, b, c) {
  // ...
}
```

is that you're declaring a function and binding the name "a" to the first parameter, "b" to the second, and "c" to the third. It's by no means guaranteed, however, that any of those will *actually* be bound to a value in any given invocation of the function later.

By the same token, you can define a function without any parameters at all, and then "find" them via the `arguments` object:

```
function noArgs() {
  var a = arguments[0], b = arguments[1], c = arguments[2];
  // ...
}
```

So that's not *quite* the same as the first function, but it's close in most ways that count practically.

The "undefined" value in JavaScript is a value, but it's semantics are kind-of unusual as languages go. In particular it's not exactly the same as the `null` value. Also, "undefined" itself is not a keyword; it's just a semi-special variable name!

Comment: Could you elaborate further what you mean by `optional` as well as "not really a value" value `undefined`?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - If the variable is not given, then it will be `undefined`.

Comment: @Pointy - What do you mean by there is no guarantee that any of the declared parameters will be actually bound to a value?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey JavaScript is a **dynamic language**.  When *calling* a function, the declaration of the function is not important, including the number of parameters. Thus, you can declare a function with as many parameters as you like, but that places no restrictions on how many parameters are actually passed in when your function is called. (In that way, it's sort-of like C, at least C in the old days.) Thus, if you declare a parameter and a call is made without any parameter value supplied, the parameter will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript doesn't have default values for function parameters like other languages do.  So, you can pass as many or as little arguments as you want.

If you don't pass a value, the parameter is `undefined`.

```
function myfunction(x) {
    alert(x);
}

myfunction(); // alerts undefined
myfunction(1); // alerts 1
myfunction(1,2,3); // alerts 1
```

If you pass more parameters than are in the signature, you can use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

```
function myfunction(x) {
    alert(x);
    console.log(arguments);
}

myfunction(1,2,3); // alerts 1, logs [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Thanks. Rather than cross posting, can you please see my example I provided to David Thomas as I still get the error `undefined`

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Huh?  What's your problem?

Comment: Not a problem per se. I was referring to my follow-up question to David about passing more parameters which you have included in your answer. What I don't quite follow is what you mean by `logs`? Where does it log it?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: It logs it to your "JavaScript console".  In most browsers you can press `F12` or `Ctrl+Shift+J` to get to it.

Comment: The first sentence is out of date as of [ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)...

Answer (score 2):

You can also provide more arguments than just the one mentioned in the function

```
myFunction(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,'etc');
```

You can use the `arguments` property which is an array in order to view the provided arguments.

Comment: @albert arguments is not array its array like object [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Answer (score 1):

Because there's no error until the function expects to be able to work with the parameter that you're supposed to pass.

For example:

```
function myfunction(x) {
    return x*2;
}
```

Would throw an error; albeit probably only a `NaN` (in this case) or a `variable is undefined`.

Comment: Okay so as long as I don't reference the parameter in the function, I will not get an error? Is that right?

Comment: Now if I elaborate on the example you provide i.e. `function myfunction(a,b) { var calc = a+b; return;}` and then call upon the function `document.write(myfunction(1.2));` why is that I still get the value of `undefined` even though I am passing a parameter?

Comment: Because you're not returning anything. You have to explicitly, in your example, return a value: *either* `return calc;` or `return a+b;` (as the last line, obviously; and the latter `return` in place of the `var calc`).

Comment: So you mean I don't have to declare a variable if I do `return a+b;`?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - You can read more on `return` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Answer (score 0):

If you omit the argument, its value will be `undefined`. This enables you to create optional parameters quite easily.

Another feature is the ability to define a function with no parameters, and call it with arguments successfully, making use of the `arguments` object. This lets you easily create variable-length argument arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript console.log inside a function gives undefined as output for unpassed parameters but outside the function it gives not defined error as inside a function browsers explicitly declares the variable. For e.g

```
console.log(x)
```

gives VM1533:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined whereas

```
function test(x) {
console.log(x)
}
test();
```

gives undefined. 
It is because the function test() is rewritten by browser as:

```
function test(x) {
    var x;
    console.log(x)
    }
```

Another Example : -

```
var x =5 ;
function test(x) {
console.log(x)
}
test();
```

is still undefined as the function becomes

```
function test(x) {
    var x;
    console.log(x)
    }
```

The alert in the below example will give undefined :-

```
    var x =5;
    function test() {
    alert(x);
    var x =10;
    }

test();
```

The above function will become :-

```
 function test() {
    var x;
    alert(x);
    x =10;
    }
```

The scope of javascript variable inside a function is function level scope and not block level. For e.g.

```
function varScope() {

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++){}
        console.log("j is "+j)
    }
    console.log("i is "+i);


}
varScope();
```

will give output as :

```
j is 5 
i is 10
```

Again the function has become as :-

```
  function varScope() {
    var i;
    var j;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){}
            console.log("j is "+j)
        }
        console.log("i is "+i);
    }
```