# OpenInNewTab function not working for button ID

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I'm trying to get a button when clicked, opens a new tab with the corresponding URL based on it's ID in Javascript. I'm planning on having multiple buttons with this feature and would like them go to different sites (thus the need for different ID's) Here's my button code and Javascript, but it's not opening up in another browser:

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="adbutton" class="adbutton"  nclick="OpenInNewTab()">
    RESERVE NOW
</button>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('.adbutton').onclick = function OpenInNewTab(url) {
    var win = window.open('http://www.example.org');
    win.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You don't required selector (dot) like `('.adbutton')` when you use `getElementById` use `('adbutton')` and function you are calling it's asking `(url)` as parameter `OpenInNewTab(url)` you don't required it. If you are not passing any use `OpenInNewTab()`

```
 document.getElementById('adbutton').onclick = function OpenInNewTab() {
  var win = window.open('http://www.example.org');
  win.focus();
  }
```

check working demo https://jsfiddle.net/zvj2o7fy/7/ I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: This one worked, however I'm trying to add this button within a figcaption and it's somehow disabling the javascript. Any ideas? Are button's able to work within a figcaption?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not passing any params to the function and it requires one, put (this.id) or (this.href) or whatever in the onclick call

```js
function OpenInNewTab(id){
  alert(id);
var win = window.open('http://www.example.org');
  win.focus();
  }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="adbutton" class="adbutton" onclick="OpenInNewTab(this.id)">RESERVE NOW</button>
```

Comment: Do we really need to pass the argument? Wont it be assinged undefined?
This link can help us
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107823/what-happens-if-i-dont-pass-a-parameter-in-a-javascript-function

Comment: his original function has an argument going in but it wasn't added in the onclick, and he writes that he wants the URL choice based on the onclick ID so that is why i added one, and no it's not undefined if there's an ID, there are other ways of doing it, just passing in this then getting all info from click, doing the event handler in js with no need for HTML onclick, etc.etc, but this is a quick example to help the problem at hand

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the **.** from

```
 document.getElementById('.adbutton')
```

and change it to

```
document.getElementById('adbutton')
```

and if you want to use the class selector you need to replace it with

```
document.getElementsByClassName('adbutton')[0].onclick = function OpenInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open('http://www.example.org');
  win.focus();
}
```

[WORKING MODEL](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/jx9mpkkq/3/)

Since the button already have onclick attribute you dont need this

`document.getElementById('adbutton').onclick`.

You can simply define the function

```
function OpenInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open('http://www.example.org');
  win.focus();
}
```

[WORKING MODEL 2](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/jx9mpkkq/4/)