# Is there a reason to call .bind() with no arguments?

Tags: javascript

I saw this code from [this site](http://ben.akrin.com/?p=5997):

```
websocket_client.on( "eval_callback",function(data){data=atob(data),eval(data)}.bind() ) ;
```

Specifically I'm wondering about

```
function(data){data=atob(data),eval(data)}.bind()
```

I'm wondering if there is a purpose to call `.bind()` with no arguments.

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107823/what-happens-if-i-dont-pass-a-parameter-in-a-javascript-function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `.bind()` with no arguments is equivalent to calling it with the argument `undefined`. This would be useful if you want to ensure that the function has no context if it tries to use `this`.

In your example,the function calls `eval()`, so I guess they want to ensure that the evaluation doesn't have any `this` context.

Comment: This answer explains bind with some examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method

Comment: [Which is also equivalent to `bind(global)`](https://tio.run/##VY4xDoMwDEX3nMLqlAxFnQvhLoHENCiyK0JZUM@eBgJS8WT//@zv0Swm9pN/z3di61LCD/WzZwKUahUe5fzyUWs9BO5MUD1T5OCqwIO8tW1Rm@amauFCdPDvb5tZ/wrB3ahXpCfmPt/d5gopN2IxE@RI6xB0UavOk5W75MlZVR92pne4RF7g47ca4LRP@AFbXeAdK3XYUqX0Aw).