# binary tree add an undefined node

Tags: javascript, data-structures, tree

***Problem***

I'm trying to study better the tree theory, i can add one or more node without problems but i noticed that if i tried to launch multiple add function without pass a parameter, simply it doesn't work. Could you explain where is my mistake ?

***Code***

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.makeNode = function(value) {
    var node = {};
    node.value = value;
    node.left = null;
    node.right = null;
    return node;
};

BinarySearchTree.prototype.add = function(value) {
    var currentNode = this.makeNode(value);
    if (!this.root) {
        this.root = currentNode;
    } else {
        this.insert(currentNode);
    }

    return this;
};

BinarySearchTree.prototype.insert = function(currentNode) {
    var value = currentNode.value;
    var traverse = function(node) {
        if (value > node.value) {
            if (!node.right) {
                node.right = currentNode;
                return;
            } else traverse(node.right);
        } else if (value < node.value) {
            if (!node.left) {
                node.left = currentNode;
                return;
            } else traverse(node.left);
        }
    };
    traverse(this.root);
};
```

Now if i try to

```
var bst = new BinarySearchTree();
bst.add(3).add(2);
console.log(bst);
```

i will have this `console.log` [image]

if i try to pass an undefined value

```
var bst = new BinarySearchTree();
    bst.add().add(2);
    console.log(bst);
```

[image: console.log]

***Expectation***

I expect that the last console.log doesn't lost the value of 2.

.   i read this post to understand better what if i didn't pass any value to a function

[What happens if I don't pass a parameter in a Javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107823/what-happens-if-i-dont-pass-a-parameter-in-a-javascript-function)
and other posts ( like medium and stack overflow ) and guide related to the tree theory but i didn't find any solution

***SOLUTION***

Thanks to the recommendation and the correction of @Nina Scholz i just added this lines to this function

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.add = function(value) {
    if (typeof value == 'undefined') {
        value = null;
    }
    var currentNode = this.makeNode(value);
    if (!this.root) {
        this.root = currentNode;
        console.log('sei qui')
    } else {
        this.insert(currentNode);
    }

    return this;
};
```

Comment: What are you want to happen if you call `add()` without parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing happens, because both conditions evaluate with `undefined` as `value` to false.

```
if (value > node.value) {
    // ...
} else if (value < node.value) {
    // ...
}
```

```js
function BinarySearchTree() {}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.makeNode = function(value) {
    var node = {};
    node.value = value;
    node.left = null;
    node.right = null;
    return node;
};

BinarySearchTree.prototype.add = function(value) {
    var currentNode = this.makeNode(value);
    if (!this.root) {
        this.root = currentNode;
    } else {
        this.insert(currentNode);
    }

    return this;
};

BinarySearchTree.prototype.insert = function(currentNode) {
    var value = currentNode.value;
    var traverse = function(node) {
        if (value > node.value) {
            if (!node.right) {
                node.right = currentNode;
                return;
            } else traverse(node.right);
        } else if (value < node.value) {
            if (!node.left) {
                node.left = currentNode;
                return;
            } else traverse(node.left);
        }
    };
    traverse(this.root);
};

var bst = new BinarySearchTree();
bst.add(3).add(2).add();
console.log(bst);
```