# Im struggling with a Type Error on this simple tip calculator project

Tags: javascript, forms, typeerror

this is a simple tip calculator project.  The function works as intened and console logs the values.  When i run the appendData() function it throws a typeerror on line 21 when im trying to update the HTML?  Any reasons why would be appreciated

```
const billAmount = document.querySelector('#bill-amount')
const guests = document.querySelector('#people')
const service = document.querySelector('#service')
const submit = document.getElementById('submit')
const output = document.getElementById('output')
const billOutput = document.getElementById('bill-amount-output')
const tipAmountOutput = document.getElementById('tip-amount')
const tipAmountPerPersonOutput = document.getElementById('tip-person-amount')


function calculateTip (bill, service, guests) {
     function tipPercent() {
        if (service.value == "1") {
            return 0.05
        } else if (service.value == "2") {
            return 0.1
        } else
            return 0.2
    }
       var tipAmount = bill.value * tipPercent()
       var tipPerGuest = tipAmount / guests.value
       return {tipAmount:tipAmount, tipPerGuest:tipPerGuest}
;}

function appendData() {
      billOutput.innerHTML = `£${billAmount.value}` 
      tipAmountOutput.innerText = `£${calculateTip().tipAmount}` 
      output.style.display = 'block'     
}

submit.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(calculateTip(billAmount, service, guests))
    appendData()
    
})
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Is there supposed to be something after `tipAmountPerPersonOutput.innerText =`?

Comment: If you are asking about an error, you should always include the full, exact text of the error and point out what line number the error pertains to. In your case, a good guess would be that this line `tipAmountPerPersonOutput.innerText = ` is the problem because you haven't completed the statement.

Comment: also, calculateTip method requires 3 parameters, but you are not passing any in appendData

Comment: script.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at calculateTip (script.js:21)
    at appendData (script.js:28)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (script.js:36)
calculateTip @ script.js:21
appendData @ script.js:28
(anonymous) @ script.js:36
script.js:35   this is the error. the blank after final statement is making no difference as far as i can see. what could be passed into appendData? am i better just using the statements on the button click as opposed to separating into another function?

Comment: Since the line numbers in your code don't match up with the line numbers here in your question, you should let us know exactly which line in your post the error is coming from.

Comment: the console.log in the eventlistener throws up  {tipAmount: 5, tipPerGuest: 2.5} which is expected. im using appendData() to try and display those values in some HTML elements.  The code runs with no error then throws the above error when i try run appendData.  The line is "var tipAmount = bill.value * tipPercent()" and its saying is cant read the value of undefined. which is confusing as the log is throwing out a value from the same line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens if I don't pass a parameter in a Javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107823/what-happens-if-i-dont-pass-a-parameter-in-a-javascript-function)

Comment: Nonik's comment is correct. The error is because you are calling calculateTip with no arguments in appendData.

Comment: thank you, ive just deleted the function and added the statements to the eventListener....its pushing the HTML now but it says undefined as opposed to a number.  it this line correct?  "tipAmountOutput.innerText = `£${calculateTip().tipAmount}"

Comment: No, you still aren't passing any arguments to calculateTip.

Comment: i am in the console.log or it wouldnt throw anything out. if i run outside of console.log the calculateTip function is returning undefined when Im trying to call calculateTip.tipAmount and calculatetip.tipPerGuest. Am i supposed to call these returned values some other way?

Comment: I have fixed this. I understand now that to get the returned key values i need to pass the parameters to every statement that uses the function so this.......const decimalTipPerPerson = calculateTip(service, guests).per.toFixed(2).....returned the correct data. thanks everyone