# How does predefined Date functions like toDateString() work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-chain

I'm currently learning prototypes in Javascript and how we can add methods to existing objects using prototypes in Javascript. I tried adding a function to Date object using Prototype.
Here's the code :

```
Date.prototype.getDayName = function () {
    return new Date().toDateString().split(" ")[0];
};
```

> The above code returns the name of the day for the current day

How do prebuilt functions like `toDateString()` in Date Object return the date string for the particular day without having to pass arguments to the `toDateString()` function? Like in the below example :

```
var date = new Date("11/03/2022");
date.toDateString();
```

How can I do the same with my `getDayName()` function *(the first code snippet in this question)* ?

**Edit:** To be further clear, all I want to know is how does the below code work?

```
var date = new Date("11/03/2022");
date.toDateString();
// Returns 'Thu Nov 03 2022'
```

How does `date.toDateString()` return the string value of the date even though no argument is passed onto the `.toDateString()` method?

Comment: related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/1846679/10666066

Comment: Do you mean like `return this.toDateString().split(" ")[0];`?

Comment: Every method receives as an implicit argument the object that it was called on, in the form of the `this` keyword.